# Get variable by language

Tags: java, android

I describe my problem.

I have my data inside a class called News, inside there are variables called text_ita, text_eng etc., depending on the language. 
How do I take various values ​​depending on the user's language?

**EDIT**

```
public class News extends CElement {

public String news_ita;
public String news_eng;
public String news_esp;
public String news_fra;
public String news_por;
}
News n = …;
//I want to it
textview.setText(n.news+language)
```

Comment: you can use different string.xml for different locales.

Comment: I can not because I get the data from a synchronization, then go into the db and then in the variables

Comment: then you can get the current locale .then select relative value

Comment: please post your code so far

Comment: you can use reflection but that's nowhere near the correct way of handling globalization. Work with multiple recourcebundles and adapt your design if necessary.

Comment: At least use an array, and a lookup table or enum, so that news[0] might be ita, news[1] eng, and so on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Should be something along these lines:

```
Locale locale = Locale.getDefault();
String lang = locale.getDisplayLanguage();

Class<?> c = myObject.getClass();
Field f = c.getDeclaredField("text_" + lang);

String value = (String) f.get(myObject);
```

Comment: While this is technically correct, using reflection is almost always a sign of design problems.

Answer (score 1):

Read this and find stuffs happens inside
http://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/languages.html

```
switch(Locale.getDefault().getDisplayLanguage())
{
  case R.id.en:

  case R.id.pt:
}
```

Comment: I can not because I get the data from a synchronization, then go into the db and then in the variables

Comment: ok... before taking the values for use check phone's language...
for ex : if(phone_language.equals("Spanish"))
// take appropriate value

Comment: I have a lot of data that are multi-lingual and I would need an automated way to do it, I had already done this thing with iOS, but I can not replicate it in Android.

Comment: Locale.getDefault().getDisplayLanguage(); get current language and set it using a switch block

Answer (score 1):

No, seriously.

Make different values folders, called values-it, values-en, ... and put your strings.xml in each folder.
The strings must have the same names in all strings.xml files.

Just yesterday I answered the very same question with a guy who needed to have the app in both English and Hebrew.

The question was that Hebrew is "dual standard": values-he and values-iw.
But "it" doesn't suffer this problem.

Comment: I have a lot of data that are multi-lingual and I would need an automated way to do it, I had already done this thing with iOS, but I can not replicate it in Android.

Comment: More automated than this? you only have to supply different strings.xml and Android does it for you - no need to use code artifacts...